# Changing Azure VM OS Family dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cloud, azure-batch

I am designing an application to connect to Azure Batch and run some compute intense jobs on demand for our users. When you create the pool you can specify the OS family and Version of VMs but what I am wondering is can you change this after the pool has been created?

So if I want to reconfigure and change to a different OS family/version, can I do so without destroying my existing pool or is the only way to close the pool and open a new one?

Answer (score 1):

No, for these types of issues I typically go to the REST API to review functionality. The REST API typically provides the most complete functionality of the any of the available APIs.

For Azure Batch you have the following operations available:

- [Replace properties of a pool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn820102.aspx)
- [Update properties of a pool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn878161.aspx)
- [Upgrade the operating system of compute nodes in a pool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn820124.aspx)

Only the "Upgrade the operating system..." link provides the ability to change the OS, and it is limited to newer versions of the same OS family.